# GAPI Is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I am having much trouble getting the Google javascript api to load in my chrome extension. Please note I am very new to javascript and even newer to chrome extensions.

I have a background.js file which executes a script

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "ChromeExtension.js" });
```

This ChromeExtension.js file then look as follows

```
//Call Initialize Method
init();

//Function To Initial Chrome Extension
function init(){
    var clientID = 'Client ID';
    var apiKey = 'API Key';
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

    loadGAPIClient();

    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);


}
```

My problem is that at

```
gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
```

I get **gapi is not defined** The thing is once my ChromeExtension.js has completed execution, gapi is fully defined and available.

I have tried other suggestions in some stack overflow questions but to no avail. I believe this is due to lack of Javascript knowledge but I would be grateful if anyone would be able to provide some assistance.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT** - Current GAPI Load

```
function () loadGAPIClient(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js";
        $("head").append(s);
}
```

This function is called in my init(), which I have also updated to reflect this.

I have also tried using jQuery.getScript among other ways.

Please understand this is my issue, I cannot find a way to correctly load the GAPI Client

Comment: Please include more details about how you are adding the GAPI script.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I have updated the question. Also I have hopefully further clarified the issue I am experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) problem.

Specifically, your `loadGAPIClient` adds a `<script>` tag which then executes the script in the page's context, which is different from the content script context.

The end result is that `gapi` becomes defined in the page's code (possibly creating a conflict if the page loaded own copy), but is still undefined in yours.

I don't see an easy way out. You can only load things in the content script context by calling `executeScript` or declaring them in the manifest; and if I recall correctly GAPI will try to load more libraries with the `<script>` injection method.

So I guess your best bet is to load the library in a background page and work with it from there, since loading external JS this way will be okay as long as you [modify the CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script).

Or alternatively, you could try [this library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/libraries/gapi-chrome-apps-lib), which works around the issues you have with default CSP and uses `chrome.identity` API. It may fit your needs, though again it won't work in a content script.

Comment: Hi Xan. Thank you for the response. Although much of the first three paragraphs I already knew, the last two were most helpful, especially the library provided, it resolved so much for me and made loading a much easier process. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I tried the library and wanted to point out that when using it in the background script, you have to modify the code a little: [DELETE these lines](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/libraries/gapi-chrome-apps-lib/gapi-chrome-apps.js#L37-#L44), since in background page `chrome.app.runtime` is actually `undefined`. After that, it works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't threat my answer as offensive, in your code snippet there isn't evidence of that, you have load the Google APIs JavaScript library as show on the [reference](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript?hl=en#specifying_an_onload_callback)?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plus.js?onload=init"></script>
```

You need to use this method, doesn't call init by hand: let's gapi call for you :)

Comment: Not helpful in the context of a Chrome extension, sorry.

Comment: Helped me in my context, thanks fellow devs! long live computing!

Comment: what if we save that file js and load it under manifest content script ?