# Fire Google+ sign out from within Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-api

I'm trying to fire off the Google+ sign out method (`gapi.auth.signOut()`) from within an Angular controller using a simple `ng-click`, but I keep getting the following error: `gapi is not defined`.

Below is my click handler:

html:

```
<div id="logout" ng-click='navbar.logOut()'>
```

relevant controller code:

```
vm.logOut = function() {
  gapi.auth.signOut();
};
```

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? I'm assuming at some point you are using gapi to log the user in? Is the error being called when the page loads or when you click the logout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433744/gapi-is-not-defined

Comment: it google api an angular injection ? maybe you've forgot to add it.